# How can I redirect URL to poin to to another app directory?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to point server to another app instance (in another FTP subdirectory) with .htaccess?

On my FTP server I have directories like www1, www2, www3 - each with its own versioned instance of a website. I'd like to switch the address `www.domain.com` to the desired directory when something goes wrong.

Comment: Shortly put, no. This is not the purpose of .htaccess / mod_rewrite

Comment: What do you mean `something goes wrong`?